# Sublime text filter out files with given extension

Tags: sublimetext

Is there a way to filter out files by extension in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

add `file_exclude_patterns` to your user preferences file. this is how mine looks like:

```
"file_exclude_patterns":
[
    "*.tmTheme.cache",
    "*.tmPreferences.cache",
    "*.tmLanguage.cache",
    "*.pyc",
    "*.pyo",
    "*.exe",
    "*.dll",
    "*.obj",
    "*.o",
    "*.a",
    "*.lib",
    "*.so",
    "*.dylib",
    "*.ncb",
    "*.sdf",
    "*.suo",
    "*.pdb",
    "*.idb",
    ".DS_Store",
    "*.class",
    "*.psd",
    "*.db"
],
```

Comment: Is it also possible to explicitly *include* some files? For example using TypeScript I don't want to see generated *.js, but several files I want to include in the project (e.g. `requirejs.dependencies.js`). Thank you!

Comment: great, tx.. i tried file_include_patterns, but it seems to be an either/or setting.. if used alone file_include_patterns works, but if used _with_ file_exclude_patterns, no files are shown..

Comment: With some careful structuring, you can avoid auto-generated JS files while still keeping the ones that you want (ie, config files) - like so:
`"file_exclude_patterns":
 [
 "*.js.map",
 "app/controllers/*.js"
 ]`

Since we're specifically filtering only on certain folders, we can separate out anything that we want to keep!

Comment: Is it possible to *extend* the default `file_exclude_patterns` rather than redefining it from scratch, via user preferences? I want to add a few without having to redefine the whole default set.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `"file_exclude_patterns"`, you can also use `"folder_exclude_patterns"`.

Referencing [this comment from zbynour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241744/sublime-text-filter-out-files-with-given-extension#comment18399247_10245021): with an appropriate product directory structure, combining both directives makes it easy to exclude folders with compiled TypeScript output, sass-cache, etc without excluding e.g. all .js files.

Also, you can specify these exclusions on a per-project basis using your project's .sublime-project file. Here's one of my .sublime-project files, which lives in the project's root directory.

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "path": ".",
      "folder_exclude_patterns": [".sass-cache"],
      "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pdf", "*.psd"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, you can also use these directives together in your `User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file. Doing so will of course affect all of your sublime sessions, for all open folders and/or projects, which for me, having forgotten about the setting several months later, caused some bewildering, head-scratching confusion.